# Calcular los minutos de diferencia entre dos horas

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo dos horas cada una en su respectivo **jTextField**, lo que necesito saber es qué hacer para restar esas dos horas, y calcular solamente los minutos de diferencia al momento de presionar el botón respectivo.

La hora de inicio la traigo de **SQL** con este formato: `*2018-08-14 9:31*`
La hora de salida se toma del sistema en este formato: `9:50`

Quisiera saber que se tiene que hacer para calcular en el **Jtetxfield** por ejemplo:

> Tiempo: 19 (minutos).

Les dejo el código que hasta ahora llevo:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String in = txtHoraInicio.getText();
    String fin = txtHoraSalida.getText();
    int inicio = Integer.parseInt(in);
    int salida = Integer.parseInt(fin);
    int diferencia = (salida - inicio);
    String dif = Integer.toString(diferencia);
    txtTiempo.setText(dif);
```

Comment: aquí hacen lo que tú buscas, solo tienes que adaptarlo a lo que tienes: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Java/3676-Diferencia-de-dias-entre-dos-fechas.html

Comment: Revisa esto amigo te puede servir:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Gettheminutesdifference.htm

Comment: Esos asteriscos van en el String?

Answer (score 1):

Falta ampliar información:

- hora salida: es la hora del sistema pero de que **tipo**? Date, Calendar,etc.

Suponiendo que hora salida es de tipo **Calendar**

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    //hora de inicio no la traes de JtextField, si no que la tomas de donde la tengas de tipo Date
    Calendar calInicio =Calendar.getInstance();
    calInicio.setTime(horaInicio)//pasamos horaInicio a Calendar
    Calendar calSalida =Calendar.getInstance();//hora actual sistema
    //calculamos diferencia
    int difHoras =calSalida.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - calInicio.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int difMinutos =calSalida.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - calInicio.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int difSegundos =calSalida.get(Calendar.SECOND) - calInicio.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    Calendar calDif =Calendar.getInstance();//variable para diferencia de tiempo
    calDif.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, difHoras);
    calDif.set(Calendar.MINUTE, difMinutos);
    calDif.set(Calendar.SECOND, difSegundos);
    int totalminutos =calDif.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 60 + calDif.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    String strTotalMinutos =Integer.toString(totalminutos);
    txtTiempo.setText(strTotalMinutos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es extraer las horas que tienes en forma de String y pasarlas a un objeto tipo Date, si el formato que ocupas es 2018-08-14 9:31, lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm", Locale.US);
public static SimpleDateFormat sdfResult = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
public static SimpleDateFormat sdfResultMinutos = new SimpleDateFormat("m", Locale.US);

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Date difference = getDifferenceBetwenDates(sdf.parse("2018-11-01 9:31"), sdf.parse("2018-11-01 9:33"));
    System.out.println(sdfResult.format(difference)); //00:02:00
    System.out.println(sdfResultMinutos.format(difference) + " Minutos"); //2 Minutos

    Date difference2 = getDifferenceBetwenDates(sdf.parse("2018-11-01 9:31"), sdf.parse("2018-11-01 11:28"));

    System.out.println(sdfResult.format(difference2)); //01:57:00
    System.out.println(sdfResultMinutos.format(difference2) + " Minutos"); //57 Minutos
}

public static Date getDifferenceBetwenDates(Date dateInicio, Date dateFinal) {
    long milliseconds = dateFinal.getTime() - dateInicio.getTime();
    int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
    int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    int hours = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Lo que estas haciendo primero es convertir el valor actual de tu fecha a Date, esto lo haces con la función `parse` de `SimpleDateFormat` recuerda que esta función requiere que captures una posible excepción, una ves en Date, lo puedes pasar a milisegundos mediante la función getTime() esto te dara un tipo `long`, te restaría obtener la diferencia entre estos dos valores y dividirlos para obtener segundos, minutos y horas, posteriormente crear un objeto Calendar y le asignas los segundos minutos y horas calculados previamente, al llamar la función `getTime()` de `Calendar` obtienes un objeto tipo `Date`, el cual posteriormente puedes darle formato a tu gusto mediante `SimpleDateFormat`.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo realmente como lo haces, pero aquí te dejo un ejemplo que te va ayudar:

```
Public void calcularTiempo(){ //Método para saber la hora
    //Llamamos al obbjeto
    Date myDate = new Date();
    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Cogemos el tiempo en que has iniciado el programa
    long tempsFinal = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Calculamos el tiempo de ejecucion del programa
    long diferenciaTemps = tempsFinal - inicio; //Restamos el tiempo de ejecución por el decuando lo iniciaste
    //Conversion de horas,minutos,segundos respecto a milisegundos 
    SimpleDateFormat formatTemps = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    //Canviamos formato de franja horaria CET a UTC
    formatTemps.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    //Imprimimos el tiempo en la consola
    System.out.println("Tiempo: "+formatTemps.format(diferenciaTemps));
```

Lo suyo es hacerlo con un método a parte para no llenar mucho el main de código.

PD: Es la primera vez que ayudo, si no entiendes algo estaré encantado de repetirlo/modificarlo

Answer (score -1):

Si te arroja un Date() entonces usa `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`:

```
long diferencia=fecha1.getTime()-fecha2.getTime();
minutos = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diferencia);
```

Y el valor arrojado será en minutos.